# Updating label in UITableViewCell with UIStepper in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uistepper

I'm a Swift beginner and I'm trying to make a simple app for ordering food. The user could add a new order by setting food `name`, `price` and `serving`. After adding an order, that order will be shown on the tableView as a `FoodTableViewCell`, and the user could change the serving with an UIStepper called `stepper` in each cell. Each order is a `FoodItem` stored in an array called `foodList`, and you can see all orders listed in a tableView in `ShoppingListVC`.

My problem is: **When I press "+" or "-" button on `stepper`, my `servingLabel` doesn't change to corresponding value.** I tried to use `NotificationCenter` to pass serving value to `stepper`, and store new value back to `food.serving` after `stepperValueChanged` with delegate pattern. However, there still seems to be some bugs. I've been kind of confused after browsing lots of solutions on the Internet. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

I removed `NotificationCenter` and `addTarget` related methods as @Tarun Tyagi 's suggestion. Now my UIStepper value turns back to 1 whereas the servingLabels are showing different numbers of serving. Since NotificationCenter doesn't help, how can I connect the label and stepper value together? Is it recommended to implement another delegate?

Here are my codes(Updated on July 8):

**FoodItem**

```
class FoodItem: Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: FoodItem, rhs: FoodItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
    
    var name: String
    var price: Int
    var serving: Int
    var foodID: String
    
    init(name: String, price: Int, serving: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.serving = serving
        self.foodID = UUID().uuidString
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ShoppingListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var foodList = [FoodItem]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
       
        ...
        
        for i in 1...5 {
            let testItem = FoodItem(name: "Food\(i)", price: Int.random(in: 60...100), serving: Int.random(in: 1...10))
            self.foodList.append(testItem)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    ...
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell
        
        let food = foodList[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = food.name
        cell.priceLabel.text = "$\(String(food.price)) / serving"
        cell.servingLabel.text = "\(String(food.serving)) serving"
        
        cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
        
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - FoodTableViewCellDelegate Method.

extension ShoppingListVC: FoodTableViewCellDelegate {
    
    func stepper(_ stepper: UIStepper, at index: Int, didChangeValueTo newValue: Double) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FoodTableViewCell else { return }
        let foodToBeUpdated = foodList[indexPath.row]
        
        print("foodToBeUpdated.serving: \(foodToBeUpdated.serving)")
        
        foodToBeUpdated.serving = Int(newValue)
        print("Value changed in VC: \(newValue)")
        
        cell.servingLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.0f", newValue)) serving"
    }
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
    
    protocol FoodTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
      func stepper(_ stepper: UIStepper, at index: Int, didChangeValueTo newValue: Double)
    }
    
    class FoodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var servingLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
        
        weak var delegate: FoodTableViewCellDelegate?
        
        @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
            sender.minimumValue = 1
            servingLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)) serving"
            // Pass the new value to ShoppingListVC and notify which cell to update using tag.
            print("sender.value: \(sender.value)")
            delegate?.stepper(stepper, at: stepper.tag, didChangeValueTo: sender.value)
        }
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            print(stepper.value)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876739/swift-increment-label-with-stepper-in-tableview-cell/42877313#42877313 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832352/swift-how-to-set-uistepper-value-from-another-class/49832459#49832459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `FoodTableViewCell` is the ONLY target for `UIStepper` value changed (looking at `@IBAction` inside `FoodTableViewCell`).

When you dequeue a cell to display on screen, you call -

```
cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

which causes your `ShoppingListVC` instance to be added as an additional target **every time** a `cellForRow` call is executed.

Things to fix :

1. Remove all of your `NotificationCenter` related code from both classes.
2. Remove `cell.stepper.addTarget()` line as well.

This would give you a better idea of why it is happening this way. Update your question with these changes in case you still don't have what you want.

---

##### UPDATE

```
// Inside cellForRow
cell.stepper.value = food.serving
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just removed the two things you mentioned in my code, which brings my UIStepper value back to 1 whereas the servingLabels are showing different numbers. Since NotificationCenter doesn't help, how can I connect the label and stepper value together? Is it recommended to implement another delegate?

Comment: Please update your question description to show the latest updated code after you have implemented the suggested changes.

Comment: I just updated the question description. Thank you.

Comment: See the **UPDATE**.

Comment: Apparently, I made things too complicated. Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Cell Config:

```
  protocol FoodTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
     func stepper(sender: FoodTableViewCell)
    }

@IBAction func stepperButtonTapped(sender: UIStepper) {
    delegate?.stepperButton(sender: self)
    stepperLabel.text = "\(Int(countStepper.value))"
}
```

Controller Config:

cellForRow:

```
    cell.countStepper.value = Double(foodList[indexPath.row].serving);
    cell.stepperLabel.text = "\(Int(cell.countStepper.value))"
```

Delegate Method:

```
func stepperButton(sender: FoodTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender){
        print(indexPath)
        foodList[sender.tag].serving = Int(sender.countStepper.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check value stepper pod it will help you: [Value stepper](https://github.com/BalestraPatrick/ValueStepper)

Integrate value stepper pod and use below code for basic implementation.

```
import ValueStepper

let valueStepper: ValueStepper = {
let stepper = ValueStepper()
stepper.tintColor = .whiteColor()
stepper.minimumValue = 0
stepper.maximumValue = 1000
stepper.stepValue = 100
return stepper
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()       
valueStepper.addTarget(self, action: "valueChanged:",     forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

@IBAction func valueChanged1(sender: ValueStepper) {
// Use sender.value to do whatever you want
}
```

Its simplify custom stepper implantation.Take outlet of value stepper view in table tableview and use it.